# How to select by time string condition in SQL?

Tags: hive, hiveql

In my table, I have a column 'send_time', which is String:

```
2018-07-04 09:15:05
```

If I want to select all records after 2018-07-04, how to write that SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_date` function.

```
to_date(send_time) > '2018-07-04'
```

Comment: select count(*) from answer_info where to_date(send_time) > 2018-07-04, which doesn't generate any results. But I do have records after this date. Any issue with the query?

Comment: the date literal should be quoted..may be that's the reason you don't see results.